# Antonym of cap as in limit from the top

Tags: antonyms

There is a verb 'cap' which means to limit value from the top. Like cap at 100, which means every value above 100 would be changed to 100. Is there a similar short word for the same operation, but from the bottom?

Comment: You should look at "floor"—although it means "at least as much as this, all lower values excluded" (the reverse of "at most this, all higher values excluded" for cap).

Comment: Floor as a verb has other meanings, as in "I floored him with my display of arcane knowledge"."

Comment: "floor", "ground", "base", "bedrock", "support", "backstop", "found", "initiate", "originate", "lead", "start at", "seat", "settle", "undergird", "underpin" may work in some situations. In my case, I think I will use "**catch**".

Comment: In computer programming, we commonly use the function `clamp(x, low, high)` to limit a value at _both_ ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the word "underpin" as a verb. Most dictionaries give definitions based on underpinning buildings but here is a quotation of underpin being used  to mean a lower limit:

> What is an underpin?   A pension scheme may have its main element as
>   either money purchase or defined benefit, but the sponsoring employer
>   could have chosen to give scheme members the ‘backup’ of an underpin. 
>   In both cases (whether the main element is money purchase or defined
>   benefit), the scheme is treated as a defined benefit scheme in the way
>   it operates, but the underpin can be created in different ways.   In
>   its simplest format, the underpin provides you with two alternative
>   pensions from the same pension scheme.   Whenever you draw your
>   pension benefits, you will get the better of the main scheme benefit
>   or the underpin. You can have a: money purchase scheme with a defined
>   benefit underpin or a defined benefit scheme with a money purchase
>   underpin.

From [Extract from MyCompanyPension.co.uk](http://www.mycompanypension.co.uk/What-is-an-Underpin-Pensioner-Members-MP)